# Coding R script to separate multiple samples (2 columns per sample) with 2 header rows for analysis

Tags: r

I am working on programming a script that takes a raw data file (saved as a .csv) for analysis.

The data in the raw data .csv is similar to following:

```
| Sample Name | (Blank)        | Sample Name 2 | (Blank)       |
| Time        |  Absorbance    | (Time)        | (Absorbance)  |
|-------------|----------------|---------------|---------------|
| Time 0      | (Abs value 1)  | Time 0        | (Abs value 1) |
| Time 1      | (Abs value 2)  | Time 1        | (Abs value 2) |
...
| Time 600    | (Abs value 600)| Time 600      | (Abs value 600|
```

There are upwards of 18 samples in a single raw data output file. Currently, the program requires saving each individual samples as its own .csv - which is time consuming and fills file folders quickly. To do this I copy the two columns for the sample excluding the sample name to a new .csv and save the new .csv file as the sample name, prior to running the program in R.

How can I change this so that a script can separate each sample out individually or allow me to select samples for analysis by script?

The current setup requires saving individual files for each sample as their own .csv - eliminating the first row by using the sample name in row 1 of raw data as the sample name (which is used for output files).

Use file.choose() to select the .csv of single sample for analysis when program is ran.

Answer (score 0):

Consider storing *all* samples in a single data frame with a `sample` identifying column. This would require some wrangling to parse the sample names into separate adjacent columns and re-organize data to stack all samples together. See below using an randomized example to replicate your structure:

**Raw Data with sample columns**

```r
sample_raw <- read.csv("Input.csv", check.names = FALSE)
head(sample_raw)
#   Sample Name 1                   Sample Name 2                    Sample Name 3                  
# 1          Time        Absorption          Time         Absorption          Time        Absorption
# 2             0 0.663187364838517             0  0.086655816331682             0 0.413866811045433
# 3             1 0.783205192424163             1  0.941775807196795             1 0.976775998739926
# 4             2 0.440702039285938             2 0.0970152372937397             2 0.793358759212642
# 5             3 0.745560761240061             3 0.0736081572443232             3 0.478393926329584
# 6             4 0.132851925608964             4  0.919646031949991             4 0.219149607976949

# RETRIEVE UNIQUE SAMPLES
samples <- colnames(sample_raw)[seq(1, ncol(sample_raw), by = 2)]

# ADD PREFIX NUMBERS TO SECOND COLUMN HEADERS
sample_raw[1, ] <- paste0(
  sort(rep(seq_along(samples), 2)), sample_raw[1, ]
)

# ASSIGN SAMPLE# COLUMNS
sample_raw[paste0(seq_along(samples), "Sample")] <- rbind(
  paste0(seq_along(samples), "Sample"), 
  sapply(samples, rep_len, nrow(sample_raw)-1)
)
head(sample_raw)
#   Sample Name 1                   Sample Name 2                 .1 Sample Name 3                .2       1Sample       2Sample       3Sample
# 1         1Time       1Absorption         2Time        2Absorption         3Time       3Absorption       1Sample       2Sample       3Sample
# 2             0 0.663187364838517             0  0.086655816331682             0 0.413866811045433 Sample Name 1 Sample Name 2 Sample Name 3
# 3             1 0.783205192424163             1  0.941775807196795             1 0.976775998739926 Sample Name 1 Sample Name 2 Sample Name 3
# 4             2 0.440702039285938             2 0.0970152372937397             2 0.793358759212642 Sample Name 1 Sample Name 2 Sample Name 3
# 5             3 0.745560761240061             3 0.0736081572443232             3 0.478393926329584 Sample Name 1 Sample Name 2 Sample Name 3
# 6             4 0.132851925608964             4  0.919646031949991             4 0.219149607976949 Sample Name 1 Sample Name 2 Sample Name 3
```

**Clean Data with one column header**

```r
# RESET DATAFRAME FOR SINGLE COLUMN HEADERS
sample_clean <- setNames(
  sample_raw[2:nrow(sample_raw),], sample_raw[1,]
) |> `row.names<-`(NULL)

# REORDER COLUMNS BY SUFFIX NUMBER
sample_clean <- sample_clean[sort(colnames(sample_clean))]

# SPLIT SAMPLES REMOVING PREFIXES
sample_dfs <- split.default(
  sample_clean, sort(rep(seq_along(samples), length(samples)))
) |> lapply(
  \(df) setNames(df, sub("[0-9]", "", colnames(df)))
)
str(sample_dfs)
# List of 3
#  $ 1:'data.frame':    51 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ Absorption: chr [1:51] "0.663187364838517" "0.783205192424163" "0.440702039285938" "0.745560761240061" ...
#   ..$ Sample    : chr [1:51] "Sample Name 1" "Sample Name 1" "Sample Name 1" "Sample Name 1" ...
#   ..$ Time      : chr [1:51] "0" "1" "2" "3" ...
#  $ 2:'data.frame':    51 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ Absorption: chr [1:51] "0.086655816331682" "0.941775807196795" "0.0970152372937397" "0.0736081572443232" ...
#   ..$ Sample    : chr [1:51] "Sample Name 2" "Sample Name 2" "Sample Name 2" "Sample Name 2" ...
#   ..$ Time      : chr [1:51] "0" "1" "2" "3" ...
#  $ 3:'data.frame':    51 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ Absorption: chr [1:51] "0.413866811045433" "0.976775998739926" "0.793358759212642" "0.478393926329584" ...
#   ..$ Sample    : chr [1:51] "Sample Name 3" "Sample Name 3" "Sample Name 3" "Sample Name 3" ...
#   ..$ Time      : chr [1:51] "0" "1" "2" "3" ...
```

**Stacked Data with all samples**

```r
# STACK SAMPLES, CLEAN AND RE-ORDER COLUMNS
sample_df <- do.call(
  rbind, unname(sample_dfs)
) |> within({
  Time <- as.integer(Time)
  Absorption <- as.numeric(Absorption)
}) |> subset(
  select = c(Sample, Time, Absorption)
)
head(sample_df)
#          Sample Time Absorption
# 1 Sample Name 1    0  0.6631874
# 2 Sample Name 1    1  0.7832052
# 3 Sample Name 1    2  0.4407020
# 4 Sample Name 1    3  0.7455608
# 5 Sample Name 1    4  0.1328519
# 6 Sample Name 1    5  0.4945091

tail(sample_df)
#            Sample Time Absorption
# 148 Sample Name 3   45  0.5335245
# 149 Sample Name 3   46  0.9419045
# 150 Sample Name 3   47  0.2715703
# 151 Sample Name 3   48  0.1244490
# 152 Sample Name 3   49  0.7975759
# 153 Sample Name 3   50  0.7890567
```

Now whenever you need a specific sample, simply subset this stacked data by `sample` column.